# How do I get the size of a Gtk widget?

Tags: application-development, gtk, widgets

I am developing an app using Quickly + Glade + Gtk + Python. I would have liked to know the size of a displayed widget. Here is what I wrote already:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit
[…]
self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
[…]
print self.webview.size_request()
```

I had expected a tuple in the form of `(100px, 200px)` for example. But what I get instead is `<GtkRequisition at 0x24607c0>`. Why is that? What should I do instead?

It seems that the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234223/in-gtk-how-do-i-get-the-actual-size-of-a-widget-on-screen), but I unfortunately don't understand it.

Comment: You may want to post your question in Stack Overflow instead of here; Ask Ubuntu is mainly used for user questions, not developer ones.

Comment: OK thank you. If I get an answer there earlier than here, I'll repost it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will want to use `width = widget.get_allocation().width` to get the width and `height = widget.get_allocation().height` to get the height as there is a difference between a widgets requested size and it's actual size.